# how to use left join to combine 2 dataframe with specific output

Tags: r, dplyr

1 have 2 dataframe
it looks like

df1

```
Store_type  Total_Amount   prod_subcat_code 
<chr>       <dbl>          <int>     
e-Shop      4265.300       4
e-Shop      8270.925       1
TeleShop    1748.110       3
e-Shop      4518.345       1
e-Shop      2568.020       3
```

and
df2

```
prod_cat_code   prod_cat                   prod_sub_cat_code   prod_subcat
<chr>           <chr>                      <int>               <chr>
1               Clothing                   4                   Mens 
1               Clothing                   1                   Women    
1               Clothing                   3                   Kids 
2               Footwear                   1                   Mens 
2               Footwear                   3                   Women
```

what if I want to use left_join so that my dataframe looks like

df3

```
Store_type  prod_cat   prod_subcat_code  Total_amount 
<chr>       <chr>      <int>             <dbl>
e-shop      Clothing   4                 4265.300
```

^^a table contanin 4 columns in order^^

i have tried running

```
df1 %>% 
  left_join(select(df2, Store_type, prod_cat, prod_subcat, Total_amount,
  by =c("prod_subcat_code"="prod_sub_cat_code")))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way could be:

```
df1 %>% 
    left_join(df2, by=c("prod_subcat_code"="prod_sub_cat_code")) %>% 
    select(Store_type, prod_cat, prod_subcat_code, Total_Amount) %>% 
    filter(prod_subcat_code == 4)
```

Output:

```
  Store_type prod_cat prod_subcat_code Total_Amount
  <chr>      <chr>               <dbl>        <dbl>
1 e-Shop     Clothing                4        4265.
```

Answer (score 0):

Please provide a data sample using `dput`.

Otherwise, this should work:

```
left_join(df1,
          df2 %>% 
            select(-prod_cat_code, - prod_subcat),
          by = c("prod_subcat_code" = "prod_sub_cat_code")) %>% 
  relocate(Store_type,  prod_cat, prod_subcat_code, Total_amout)
```